# What specific types of Chinese Martial arts Does Ling Xiaoyu use in the Tekken series?

Tags: tekken

What specific types of Chinese Martial arts Does Ling Xiaoyu use in the Tekken series?

I know it says she uses "hekka" based martial arts but which martial arts does Ling use?

Answer (score 1):

She uses [Baguazhang](https://tekken.fandom.com/wiki/Baguazhang) and [Piguaquan](https://tekken.fandom.com/wiki/Piguaquan) style Chinese martial arts.

Source: https://tekken.fandom.com/wiki/Ling_Xiaoyu